# Specified cast is not valid error

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce

I am getting an error saying "Specified cast is not valid." I am not sure what to do, itried a bit but no go.

```
        List<string> productCode = new List<string>();
        List<string> productName = new List<string>();
        List<int> quantity = new List<int>();
        List<double> totalPrice = new List<double>();
        List<double> totalTax = new List<double>();
        int orderID = 0;

SqlCeCommand com2 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT TotalPrice, TotalTax FROM Order_Details WHERE OrderID = ('" + orderID + "')", con);
        SqlCeDataReader dr2 = com1.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr2.Read())
        {
            totalPrice.Add(dr2.GetDouble(0));
            totalTax.Add((double)dr2[1]);
            j++;
        }
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: Please don't use tags in title, but tag the question properly: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: What is the types of your columns?

Comment: Always add full details of the error message or exception.

Comment: why was the wpf tag edited back in?

Answer (score 1):

Is column 1 a double? That would seem to be where your problem is.

Change;

```
totalTax.Add((double)dr2[1]);
```

to;

```
totalTax.Add((dr2.GetDouble(1));
```

Is the column nullable? If it is, maybe this would be better.

```
totalTax.Add((double)(dr2[1] ?? (object)0.0));
```

A null field in this instance would indicate zero tax.

I'd say that column 1 is not a `double`, `float` or `integer` (all those casts would work). It probably not `DbNull` as that would throw a `NullReferenceException` (although im willing to be corrected on that).

Comment: Both are same. How does that helps?

Comment: if dr2 is null that will fail.   Need to check for IsDBNull.

Answer (score 0):

what type value you are getting in both field if Double the you should use  totalTax.Add((dr2.GetDouble(1)); instead of  totalTax.Add((double)dr2[1]);.

Answer (score 0):

Need to check the type in SQL and match that type in .NET
This should point out your problem

```
SqlCeCommand com2 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT TotalPrice, TotalTax FROM Order_Details WHERE OrderID = ('" + orderID + "')", con);
SqlCeDataReader dr2 = com1.ExecuteReader();
while (dr2.Read())
{
    if (dr2.IsDBNull(0))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("dr2[0] isnull ");
    }
    else 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("dr2[0] = " + dr2[0].ToString());
        totalPrice.Add(dr2.GetDouble(0));
    }
    if (dr2.IsDBNull(1))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("dr2[1] isnull ");
    }
    else 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("dr2[1] = " + dr2[1].ToString());
        totalTax.Add(dr2.GetDouble(1));
    }
    j++;
}
```